# VSCode - SQL Server (msql) Extension - Prevent query execution on tab change

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the SQL Server (msql) extension in VSCode and really liking it.

However when I want to run 2 queries I am discovering that the results will refresh every time I switch result tabs.

Both results tabs are in the same well (seems to not happen when they are in different wells)

[image]

Can I prevent this from happening and retain the original query results?

Comment: I've noticed this behavior too - I run two queries in two separate tabs, they create two result windows.  **The queries SHOULD NOT RERUN when changing the active result tab, but they do. This seems to be very dangerous behavior.** I do hope there is a setting to correct this, but this should never happen by default.  For example, if you close an active result tab, the next result tab will run its query again.

Answer (score 0):

```
"mssql.persistQueryResultTabs": true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).